# error 500 when tried to POST API with requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, python-requests

I tried to post data to external API with requests, here's my code :

```
import requests
import json

client_id = "MY_CLIENT_ID"
secret = "MY_CLIENT_SECRET"
data = {
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
    'scope': 'MY_SCOPES',
}
head_token = {
    "Client_id": client_id,
    "Client_secret": secret,
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization": "Basic SOME-RANDOM-STRING"
}
response = requests.post(
    "https://api.example.com/oauth2/token", data=data, headers=head_token)


print(response.status_code)

if response.status_code in [200]:
    resp_dict = json.loads(response.text)
    access_token = resp_dict["access_token"]
    print(access_token)

    url = 'https://api.example.com/send/data'
    data = {'some' : 'data'}
    headers = {
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': secret,
        'authorization': "Bearer %s"  %access_token,
        'content-type': "application/json",
        'accept': "application/json"
    }

    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(
        data, default=str), headers=headers)
    print(r.status_code)
```

the script succeed to get the access token, but when it hit the 2nd endpoit it always give 500 response. heres the terminal :

```
python3 test_hit.py
200
THE_ACCESS_CODE
500
```

I want to know what is the caused it give me response 500 even though I already get the access token to hit the 2nd one?

Comment: In my experience, the authorization, content-type and accept headers should all be capitalized (Authorization, Content-type, Accept). I'd change those first. Then I'd confirm that the Authorization header has been created correctly (via `print(headers)`. Do you own the endpoint? If you do, you should be able to find out what is really being logged for your 500 status code.

Comment: @JamesMcPherson I've figured the problem, it's just a documentation error. FYI for this API the headers is not case-sensitive but it some case there might be a case-sensitive headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED!**

It's a documentation error, the example they gave me is missing `[]` inside the data arguments.

I don't own the endpoint and I can't debug it from the API side.

I encounter this solution by trying hit the endpoint via postman, postman succeed to hit the 2nd endpoint, so I tried to check is there any difference between my code and postman auto-generated python code, and my code only missing `[]`.

doc:

```
data = {'sample' :{
        'data1' : 'value1'
        'data2' : 'value2'
       }}
```

my code:

```
data = {'sample' :{
        'data1' : 'value1'
        'data2' : 'value2'
       }}
```

postman auto-generated code:

```
data = {'sample' :[{
        'data1' : 'value1'
        'data2' : 'value2'
       }]}
```

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.